# PyDev does not allow me set breakpoints anymore

Tags: eclipse, pydev

PyDev does not allow me add breakpoints anymore. 
The following options show but they do not have any effect.

right click + Add Breakpoint
double click to add Breakpoint.

I tried to upgrade to  Eclipse NEON and latest version of PyDev 5.7 but it did not help.

is there anyway to fix this?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's happening (it does work for me).

Some things to test:

1. Open the debug perspective then view the breakpoints view (if the breakpoint appears here, the glitch is only in the editor).
2. Now try to do Ctrl+Shift+B on the line (this will only work in the debug view or if you customize your view to have the breakpoints actions. `i.e.: Window > perspective > customize perspective > action set availability` > make sure `breakpoints` is checked).
3. Just double-click the left ruler

If none of those worked, please check if you do have some error in your error log.

Also, is the file where you're putting a breakpoint a part of the project (i.e.: under a source folder) or is it external to the project?

Comment: Thanks Fabio, I could see the breakpoints in the debug perspective, so as you said the glitch was only in the editor.  It was fixed by checking "Show in Vertical ruler" in Preferences/General/Editors/TextEditors/Annotation.  Thanks :)